# App working in single tasking

Tags: iphone

How can make my iphone application is working both single tasking and multitasking.

Like if suppose in my application is working finely in latest  multitasking supporting devices.

But it was not working properly in single-task supporting devices..

In single-task supporting devices during run time if suppose i pressed the exit button it will not support multitasking ..
How can solve this problem..

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What multitasking functionality are you using exactly? For example: location updates or background downloads

Comment: background server connection..anyway thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your application is doing.  If your application does not post local notifications to itself, or handle external notifications, then all you may need to do differently between single and multitasking is to save your user data and important state in the

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

method to handle multi-tasking iOS's, in addition to the

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

method which will handle the single-tasking versions.   If your application is not killed while in the background in a multi-tasking OS then it will resume exactly where it was suspended, unlike the single-tasking OS where you must save all state and restore that state manually.